# Скрыть/Отобразить HTML блок, в зависимости от выбора в <select> - JS

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно что бы при выборе одной опции в выпадающем списке отображался определённый блок.

По умолчанию загружается пустое значение и дополнительный блок не нужно отображать.

После выбора определённого значения должен отображаться определённый блок.

```js
function showDiv(elem) {
  if (elem.value == 1)
    document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = "None";
  document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = "None";
  document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = "None";
  if (elem.value == 'AL')
    document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = "None";
  document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = "None";
  if (elem.value == 'WY')
    document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = "None";
  document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = "None";
  if (elem.value == 'WZ')
    document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = "None";
  document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = "None";
  document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = "block";


}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select onchange="showDiv(this)">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="AL">Prosakov Vektor</option>
    <option value="WY">Puchkov Anton</option>
    <option value="Wz">Kryp Pavel</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id='first_div' style='display: none'> </div>
<div id='second_div' style='display: none'> </div>
<div id='therd_div' style='display: none'> </div>
```

Проблема в том, что при выборе значения первый раз блок отображается, но, если выбираешь второй раз другое значение из списка - блоки не скрываются.

Comment: Попробуйте else if() сделать

Comment: не отрабатывает вообще. если перед if добавляю else

Comment: Как на счет скобок? if() {}; else if() {}; и тд

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос: А если таких блоков будет штук 50, для каждого записывать отдельное условие или кейс?) Ваш код можно упростить до нескольких строчек, при условии, что опции и блоки в HTML будут строго совпадать по индексу.

Первая опция у вас пустая, поэтому добавил вначале ненужный пустой блок, который всегда будет невидимым. Чтобы не заморачиваться с +/- индексами.

Покликайте:

```js
let select = document.getElementById('select');
let block = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
let lastIndex = 0; // После каждой смены опции, сохраняем сюда индекс предыдущего блока

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  block[lastIndex].style.display = "none"; 
  // Чтобы сразу делать именно его невидимым при следующей смене 

  let index = select.selectedIndex; // Определить индекс выбранной опции
  block[index].style.display = "block"; // Показать блок с соответствующим индексом

  lastIndex = index; // Обновить сохраненный индекс.
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="select">
    <option>- -</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="block" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
<div class="block">6</div>
<div class="block">7</div>
<div class="block">8</div>
<div class="block">9</div>
<div class="block">10</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(elem.value == ..) { your code
} else if(elem.value == ...) { your code
} else if(elem.value == ...) { your code
} else if(elem.value == ...) { your code
}
```

Comment: спасибо данный вариант получилось реализовать

Comment: Ну так отметьте, как ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
showDiv = function(elem){
      document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = "none";
      switch(elem.value){
         case 'AL':
          document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = "block";
          break;
         case 'WY':
           document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = "block";
           break;
         case 'WZ': 
           document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = "block";
           break;
      } 
}
```

Попробуй так

Answer (score 0):

Фигурные скобочки помогут. Без фигурных скобок под иф попадает только первое выражение, а остальные выполняются в любом случае.

```js
function showDiv(elem) {
    if (elem.value == 1) {
        document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = 'None';
        document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = 'None';
        document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = 'None';
    }
    if (elem.value == 'AL') {
        document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = 'None';
        document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = 'None';
    }
    if (elem.value == 'WY') {
        document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = 'None';
        document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = 'None';
    }
    if (elem.value == 'WZ') {
        document.getElementById('first_div').style.display = 'None';
        document.getElementById('second_div').style.display = 'None';
        document.getElementById('therd_div').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Немного проясню.

Если написать без скобок

```js
if (a == 2)
  b = 2;
  c = 2;
```

То `b = 2` будент выполняться только если `a == 2`. А `c = 2` будет выполнять ни смотря ни на что.

А если написать

```js
if (a == 2) {
  b = 2;
  c = 2;
}
```

То `b = 2` и `c = 2` будет выполняться только если `a == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать селектор в `value`, и не страдать.

Нужны только два общих класса для блоков: первый для их скрытия по-умолчанию (общий), и второй - для показа выбранного (отмены скрытия).

```js
function showSingleDiv(selector) {
  const prevBlockEl = document.querySelector('.single.active'),
        currBlockEl = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (!currBlockEl || prevBlockEl === currBlockEl) return;
  prevBlockEl && prevBlockEl.classList.remove('active');
  currBlockEl.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
/* чисто декоративные стили */
.single { margin: 0.5rem 0; padding: 1rem; font: 1.5rem sans-serif; text-align: center; background: #eee; }
/* а вот эти - важны */
.single { display: none; }
.single.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select onchange="showSingleDiv(this.value)">
    <option disabled selected>Показать блок</option>
    <option value="#some-id">По его id</option>
    <option value=".some-class">По его классу</option>
    <option value="[data-some-attr]">По его data-атрибуту</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="some-id" class="single">блок с id</div>
<div class="single some-class">блок с классом</div>
<div class="single" data-some-attr="any">блок с data-атрибутом</div>
```

Comment: да только правда функция берет только первое значение если поиск идёт по  classname

Comment: @WilteRatenau, все зависит только от селектора, указанного в `value`. Если селектор неточен - да, выбирается первый из подходящих элементов.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словами неточен ? Если у меня два div с одним и тем же классом , то функция найдет первый и остановиться , а мне хотелось бы оба.

Comment: @WilteRatenau, неточен - в смысле выбирает несколько элементов. В вопросе речь о переключении видимости трех одиночных элементов (блоков), чтобы был виден ***один*** из них - и ответ в точности соответствует этой задаче. Для нескольких элементов, код будет другой, потому что это уже другая задача...